# How to import from the same package

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-module

I'm using `Python 3` and `Jupyter` under `Windows 10`.

I have 2 modules: `mod_main` and `mod_sub`. I'd like to import various modules (in this case, only `os`) from `mod_sub` to `mod_main`. The approach that works for me is as follows:

**mod_main.py**

```
from pathlib import Path # works with / for any OS
import sys
sys.path.append(str(Path('C:/MyApps/Python_Base')))
from dummypackage.mod_sub import *
#from dummypackage import mod_sub
def print_path():
    print(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

**mod_sub.py**

```
import os
print('mod_sub is imported')
```

I then run the following from a Jupyter Notebook under `C:\MyApps\Python_Base`

```
from dummypackage import mod_main
import importlib
importlib.reload(mod_main)
mod_main.print_path()
```

Now, I have a couple of questions:

1. use of wildcards is [discouraged](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/from_module_import_all_used.html), but if I use `from dummypackage import mod_sub` then I won't get access to other imported modeules (`os` in this case). So, what is the best practice here?
2. is there any better ways to import a module from the same package? what I did to add the path to the parent folder and the import from package.module looks ugly. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: What about from . import ModuleName ?

Comment: that again takes me to the first problem `NameError: name 'os' is not defined`. I though from package import module imports everything, but I was wrong

Comment: Why not just `import dummypackage` ? Then you have access to everything.

Comment: No, I won't. `os` will still remain undefined

Comment: I feel like this claim "use of wildcards is discouraged, but if I use from dummypackage import mod_sub then I won't get access to other imported modeules (os in this case). So, what is the best practice here?" isn't actually true in regards to getting access to other imported modules. The module, in this case `os` that is imported by the module getting imported, is just restricted to the imported package's namespace like `imported_pkg.os`.

Comment: Why do you want to import `os` through `dummypackage`? Just do `import os`!

Comment: @Bakuriu, this is a minimal example. as the naming "Python_Base" implies, I'm trying to create a personal base of packages and modules and do the imports in related modules (e.g. `import os` in my os-related base modules)

Comment: @n8sty, so, you think it is okay to do so here, or do you think I should change my style and instead of relying on imported modules in a sub-module, I should always try to import them separately on my main modules?

Comment: @towi_parallelism I'm saying that your claim that you won't get access to other import modules is incorrect - you should probably change your style and not import a wildcard and not rely on the submodule importing libraries that you want access to